# Set selected attribute of matching option

Tags: jquery

I have a selector with several options. There's also an element on the page with a numeric value in it. I need to add SELECTED attribute to the option that matches the value in the element.

```
var myVal = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.dist').text();
$(this).closest('.panel').find('.mySelector option[value='+myVal +']').prop('selected', 'selected');


<select class="mySelector"> 
     <option>1
     <option>2
     <option>3
</select>

<span class="dist">3</span>
```

I think I'm missing something...

Comment: Close your `<option>` tags.

Comment: Also your option doesn't have value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option tags are missing the value attribute and the closing tag.

I've modified your example slightly and added a button to demonstrate the solution.

```
$("#selectButton").click(function() {
  var myVal = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.dist').text();
  $(this).closest('.panel').find('.mySelector option[value='+myVal +']').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <select class="mySelector"> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="dist">3</span>
  <input id="selectButton" type="button" value="select option" />
</div>
```